# Relay or switch that switches depending on the relative temperature

Tags: switches, relay, temperature, thermal, thermometer

I want to construct a box whose lid opens/closes when the internal temperature of the box goes from lower than the external temperature to higher  and vice versa.

The opening/closing is solved, now I just need something that switches on the electricity when the relative temperature changes. Does something like that exist, or how can I construct it myself from other components?

It is a hobby project so budget is a concern. It is gonna be outside but not exposed (in a carport), but it should handle temperatures you find in Northern Europe wintertime. It doesn't need to be extremely sensitive. Typically it will change state at sunset and dawn so if it takes a while for it to react then that is no big deal.

I found a second hand electric window opener for greenhouse windows. I just need to turn it on/off at the right moment.

Comment: Sounds like you need two thermistors and a comparator. Have you done any searching yourself?

Comment: Or something involving two bimetallic strips - but that wouldn't be an off-the-shelf part. Easier to make the one with two thermistors and a comparator. Even though it will need a battery, and be more complicated, you'll actually be able to manufacture it.

Comment: Or a thermocouple without temperature compensation.  Voltages would be teeny, though.

Comment: Welcome!  Are you more experienced in software (you could get two digital temperature sensors and write the trivial program) or want a hardware project (analogue sensors).  If you're not experienced make sure you get some good safe way to "turn on the electricity", I presume you mean mains, with a relay or similar.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson No, didn't know what to search for. Are these components "plug-n-play" or how do you connect them?

Comment: @user253751 The lift already uses 12 V so I electricity is not a problem.

Comment: @TimWescott What is that?

Comment: @jonathanjo I know how to code but it feels way more complicated (and expensice)? Something like a Raspberry PI or what do you have in mind?

Comment: @d-b What are you using to open the box? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: No, a 50 cent microcontroller that's basically a if this than that machine, two 25 cent digital tenp sensors and  a handful of passive parts to control the relay

Comment: I expect you'll find that the motor drive part is more challenging than the decision on when to drive the motors.

Comment: @NickBolton I found a second hand electric window opener for greenhouse windows. I just need to turn it on/off at the right moment.

Comment: Regardless of the actual implementation be sure to consider hysteresis - if you have only one trip value to determine high or low, system noise can cause it to oscillate. You need two trip points - one slightly higher than the required value and one slightly lower. If the output is low, test the input with the higher value to transition the output to high. If the output is high, test the input with the lower value. This gives you a ‘dead band’ that should be larger than any expected noise.

Comment: @d-b Ah, so I'm guessing it's an actuator. If so, you'll need to use an H-bridge motor driver to open and close the window.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two approaches, both pretty straightforward.  Honestly, the digital way is easier if you have any experience programming and not much experience with circuits.  I'm assuming the wires to the temperature sensors can be reasonably short, perhaps 1 metre.  If they're long you might have to take extra measures.

Whichever way you choose, you'll need some kind of [relay module](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-for-relay-module-with-arduino/) for your motor control output.  If you're driving 12 volts, many would prefer to use a MOSFET output instead -- it all depends on what your motor circuit is like.

The **digital way** would be an Arduino with two [DS18B20 digital sensors](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/256/DS18B20-370043.pdf) which directly gives the temperatures in Celsius.  You'd want to use two sensors, the kind which are on the end of a cable.  The MCU communicates with the two sensors over a simple serial protocol called 1-wire.  How you do this is shown in many tutorials ([Example 1](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/TheGadgetBoy/ds18b20-digital-temperature-sensor-and-arduino-9cc806), [Example 2](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-temperature-sensor)).  The following is pretty much everything you'd need.  (It's possible to put multiple sensors on one 1-wire bus, but it's easier in software if you give them an IO pin each.)  Pretty much any microcontroller would work, it's just what you find easiest to program.

[image]

The **analogue way** would be two thermistors and an op-amp and the associated circuitry.  The difficulty for a beginner is the "associated circuitry": for calibration, for output conditioning, for relay control.  In this circuit, one of the NTCs will be a higher temperature and a lower resistance.  The op-amp compares the two: if NTC2 (inside) is hotter, it will have a lower resistance.  The R2-NTC2 potential divider will have a lower voltage than R1-NTC1.  The op-amp amplifies the possibly small difference and drives the output.  You may well find you need something for hysteresis if that isn't provided by your mechanical system.  I've shown R1 and R2 as adjustable just for calibration.  (Here are some good notes about [op-amps](https://pfnicholls.com/Electronics/comparator.html)).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fErIZA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With apologies for the thermistors, they should be a symbol like this:
[image]

There are lots of ways you could organise the two sensors.  Here's another:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwBrOO.png)</sup>

Comment: Analog way looks more fun though! :)

Comment: @NickBolton it's horses for courses, but yes, it does make electronics people want to build things.  :-)

Comment: Well, as Dave from EEVblog puts it: "Just connecting modules together isn't real electronics."

Comment: @NickBolton it might not be [real electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman), but sometimes you have to admit those microprocessors have taken over the world for a reason.

Comment: I totally admit that, and I always go for a micro as the first port of call (it's just way faster to write out code a lot of the time). I only pursue the 'purist' route when I need to (e.g. power saving, performance, or just for the fun of learning). Great Wikipedia article by the way, on the appeal to purity informal fallacy. I suspected this was a bias that existed, but didn't know there was an actual definition for it.

Comment: @2012rcampion thanks for comment, yes that's what I meant, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a simple microcontroller and temperature sensor. There are many microcontrollers and temperature sensors to choose from, so if you're overwhelmed, [follow a tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/9-arduino-compatible-temperature-sensors-for-your-electronics-projects/).

As others have mentioned, you could use a relay module to switch whatever you're using to open/close the box, but if the device is DC, I'd personally use a transistor (e.g. MOSFET). I tend to use relays only to control AC circuits from a DC circuit.

> I found a second hand electric window opener for greenhouse windows. I just need to turn it on/off at the right moment.

If this is an actuator, you can use an H-bridge module to extend and retract it. Quite easy to control these from a microcontroller.

Comment: of course, you would use *two* temperature sensors and program the microcontroller to check which one is seeing a hotter temperature

Answer (score 3):

You could use a thermocouple, which (roughly speaking) measures differential temperature directly but that would involve some low-level (tens of microvolts) signals that might result in a circuit that is prone to chatter or susceptible to EMI.

The easiest approach is to use an Arduino Nano or similar and two [DS18B20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) one-wire sensors. Hardly any soldering, just write a small '[sketch](https://lastminuteengineers.com/multiple-ds18b20-arduino-tutorial/)' to read the two temperatures and decide the output state. The two sensors plus one resistor and the Arduino are all that is required.

Comment: "You could use a thermocouple ... but that would involve some low-level..."  But it's _fun_!

Comment: @TimWescott the engineers definition of “fun” is different to everyone else’s definition :)

Comment: @SolarMike The cool solution is sure fun. Debugging someone else's mess remotely is less so.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany agree with that.  Was once working in hard rain and someone said « are you happy working in this? » said « yes, as it is filling our reservoir… » The look of confusion…

Comment: For a commercial installation with off-the-shelf parts, a thermostat that supports thermocouples and two thermocouples connected in series (with attention given to the junction point location) would be a nice and simple solution. Such thermostats can be bought for around 30 EUR.

Comment: @jpa I don't think that would work as the thermostat would be trying to compensate the non-existent cold junction

Comment: @user253751 Good point, I think you are correct!